# What's the correct way to store an object in a Model property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store a Django template object in a Model property.

My solution so far has been to pickle the object before assigning it to a BlobProperty :

```
entity.template_blob = pickle.dumps(template)
entity.put()
```

And then after a fetch from the datastore, I do :

```
template = pickle.loads(entity.template_blob)
```

Am I doing this wrong ? I couldn't find a property suited to the storage of any object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it right. Pickling to a blob is the standard solution for this problem.

There isn't a built-in property that automatically handles the serialization / deserialization, but the [PickleProperty in aetycoon](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L284) will do this for you.